# Looking to create overlined lines of pluses in unicode

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

print("+\u0304\u203E") creates an overlined plus sign combined with an overline, but they are not aligned.  Is there a way to do this so that the overlines match up?  Thanks!

Comment: `\u0304` is the COMBINING MACRON symbol.  COMBINING OVERLINE (`\u0305`) would be more likely to match the standalone overline character.

Comment: I've tried that too, the overlines are still uneven.  Thank you though.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of to try would be to use SPACE + COMBINING OVERLINE instead of the single overline character.

Comment: `print("\u0305\u0305+")` looks pretty nice in IDLE. One problem you might run into is that different fonts might have different levels of support for combining overline. Consolas doesn't seem to like `\u203E` very much.